# convert a coordinate list in to a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I need to convert a coordinates list into a csv format file

```
x = [['52.603239607137876', '-81.2062310489267'], ['52.603361740732154', '-81.20611204483788'], ['52.60332596253358', '-81.20593347343866'], ['52.603160358705384', '-81.2059884599191']]
```

into

```
lat                    lon 
52.603239607137876     -81.2062310489267
52.603361740732154     -81.20611204483788
52.60332596253358.     -81.20611204483788
52.603160358705384.    -81.20611204483788
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this script can help you:

```
import pandas as pd

x = [['52.603239607137876', '-81.2062310489267'   ]
     , ['52.603361740732154', '-81.20611204483788']
     , ['52.60332596253358', '-81.20593347343866' ]
     , ['52.603160358705384', '-81.2059884599191' ]]

res = pd.DataFrame(x)
res.columns = ['lat', 'lon']
res.lat = res.lat.astype(float)
res.lon = res.lon.astype(float)
res.to_csv(r'directory/to/save/filename.csv', index=False)
```